# × TypeError: this.props.handleRefresh is not a function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I keep on getting the same error even after going through all the spelling errors and trying different solutions to similar issues.

`handleRefresh()` function defined in App.js.

It is supposed to find it like this:

App.js -> CoinList.jsx -> Coin.jsx

Error message is still the same even when I tried drop or add `props`

```
  19 | handleClick(event) {
  20 |    event.preventDefault();
  21 | 
> 22 |    this.props.handleRefresh(this.props.ticker);     
     | ^  23 |    
  24 |    // const randomPercentage = 0.995 + Math.random() * 0.01;
  25 |    // this.setState( function(oldState) {
```

Coin.jsx

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Td = styled.td`
   border: 2px solid black;
   width: 20vh;
`

export default class Coin extends Component {
   constructor  (props) {
      super(props);
      // this.state = {
      //    price: this.props.price 
      // }
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }
  
   handleClick(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      this.props.handleRefresh(this.props.ticker);     
      
      // const randomPercentage = 0.995 + Math.random() * 0.01;
      // this.setState( function(oldState) {
      //    return {
      //       price: oldState.price * randomPercentage
      //    };
      // })
   }
     
   render() {
      return (
         <tr>
            <Td>{this.props.name}</Td>
            <Td>{this.props.ticker}</Td>
            <Td>${this.props.price}</Td>
            <Td>
               <form action="#" method="POST">
                  <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Refresh</button>
               </form>
      
            </Td>
         </tr>
      );
   }
}

Coin.propTypes = {
   name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   ticker: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   price: PropTypes.number.isRequired 
}
```

CoinList.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Coin from '../Coin/Coin';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Table = styled.table`
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
`
export default class CoinList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Ticker</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            { 
                this.props.coinData.map(({name, ticker, price}) => 
                    <Coin key={ticker} 
                    handleRefresh={this.props.handleRefresh}
                    name={name} 
                    ticker={ticker} 
                    price={price} />
                )
            }
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    )
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import AccountBalance from './components/AccountBalance/AccountBalance';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import React from 'react'
import CoinList from './components/CoinList/CoinList';
import ExchangeHeader from './components/ExchangeHeader/ExchangeHeader';

const AppCss = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(151, 69, 201);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
`
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      balance: 20000,
      coinData: [
        {
          name: "Bitcoin", 
          ticker: "BTC",
          price: 29999.99
        },
        {
          name: "Ethereum", 
          ticker: "ETH",
          price: 1900
        },
        {
          name: "Dogecoin", 
          ticker: "DOGE",
          price: 0.003
        },
        {
          name: "Tether", 
          ticker: "USDT",
          price: 1.0
        },
        {
          name: "Solana", 
          ticker: "SOL",
          price: 50
        }

      ]
    }
    this.handleRefresh = this.handleRefresh(this);
  }

  handleRefresh(valueChangeTicker){
    const coin = this.state.coinData.find(({ticker}) => ticker === valueChangeTicker );
    console.log( coin );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppCss>
        <ExchangeHeader />
        <AccountBalance amount={this.state.balance}/>
        <CoinList coinData={this.state.coinData} handleRefresh={this.handleRefresh}/>
      </AppCss>
    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `this.handleRefresh = this.handleRefresh(this);` to `this.handleRefresh = this.handleRefresh.bind(this)`

Comment: I don't quite understand why do we need binding?

Comment: By the way, this solved the problem.

Comment: I don’t know either. It’s one of the weird things you had to do with class-based React components. One of the main reasons that function components are much more popular now.